# Getting same error again n again while uploading my aab file on google console

Tags: flutter, kotlin, keystore, uploading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQkiB.jpg)

I have uploaded the image that problem i am facing again n again. I have reset my keystore and trying to upload with the new one but still facing the same issue. I have attached the picture my keystore is same from which i am trying to upload my aab file but still I can't.

Comment: its an update or new app?

Comment: It's an update. I am editing my release and uploading .aab file

Comment: go to android/key.properties and check storefile name and use the same file don't create the new one

Comment: use the old keystore.jks file

Comment: I have tried with both old and new one. My key fingerprint is same i have checked it. I am uploading with that keystore and also check in app integrity in the Google console and it is also same SHA1